# How to reinstate a revoked licence in Illinois

Tags: driving, illinois

Around 10 years ago I was a dumb kid and made a lot of mistakes. I received two DUIs before I was 18. Since then I have changed, moved to China to live for 8 or so of those years, but I have finally moved back to the USA.

My question is what would be the process of getting it reinstated, and also is it necessary for me to hire a lawyer for it?

Answer (score 1):

You apply for a license as you would normally.

According to [this page on illinois law](https://www.edgarsnyder.com/drunk-driving/driving-alcohol-laws/illinois.html#Drivers_License_Revocation_Periods), a second DUI results in a five year ban from reapplying. This has expired.

Unless you were banned for a longer period for reasons you haven't mentioned, you should have no problem applying for a new license.

Comment: I hope its that easy hah, the only thing that worries me is i get conflicting info IE: https://www.cyberdriveillinois.com/departments/BAIID/reinstate.html